# How we Add different unit rates and sum up and show the result

Tags: java

I want to add unit.If unit is more than ***300*** then there price of per unit is different for example if unit is within *300* it multiply with **3 /per** unit but i want if we have more than *300* unit then more than *300* unit multiply with 13.330 and add the result of *300* units and more than *300* units and give a result 
for example total unit is **364** and `(300*10.200)=3060` and more than *300* unit that which is `(64*13.300) = 851.2` according to total unit then want the add the sum of both to show the result

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    double unit1 , unit2, total_unit ;

    System.out.print("enter total unit");
    unit1 = input.nextInt();
    unit2 = input.nextInt();        

    if(unit1 <= 300){
        unit1 = unit1 * 10.20;
        System.out.println("bill less than 300 " + unit1);          
    }

    if(unit2 > 300){
        unit2 = unit2 * 13.20;
        System.out.println("bill greatr than 300" + unit1);             
    }       

    total_unit = unit1 + unit2;
    System.out.println("total bill is" + total_unit);           
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear? what is the problem you are facing

Comment: So, What is your problem..?

Comment: its probably better for you to spend time on your own homework, that way you'll learn too

Comment: bro iwant to add these 2 differnet units more than 300 and less 300 units that will multiply with different values actaually a electricity bill i want to made

Comment: Your actual code is excpecting two numbers the first less then 300 and the second more then 300, if you input these it works more or less (check your error on  System.out.println("bill greatr than 300"+ unit1); unit1-->unit2,

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: i want the addtion of 2 units both couts on different rates if unit less than 300 then multiply with 10 and give the answer of this and then give the seperate answer if unit >300 for example total units is 364  300 will multiply with 10 and remainig unit multiply that is 64 that multiply with13 and at the both will add and give a result

Comment: Then why are you taking two inputs. one input is enough right ?

Comment: if one input is enough then how we take 2nd input and add both units in the end bro

Comment: for example you pass 350 then code should automatically calculate for 300+ 50 extra and give the answer. if you give less then 300 then it will directly calculate

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding from your question, I think this is what you are expecting.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("enter total unit:");
        int unit = input.nextInt();

        if (unit <= 300) {
            double total_unit = unit * 10.20;
            System.out.println("Total bill is: " + total_unit);
        }
        if (unit > 300) {
            double extra = unit - 300;
            double total_unit = 300 * 10.20 + extra * 13.20;
            System.out.println("Total bill is: " + total_unit); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bro my logic is wrong i think it will work through array and if condition is not used because i want to add unit1 and unit 2  unit1=unit*10 and unit2=unit2*13 then totalunit=unit1+unit2 that a work but i dont understand how i did

Comment: Awesome bro thanx got it now